# Firebird database connection by FireDAC after Windows 10 update

Tags: delphi, windows-10, firebird, firedac

I have some Delphi applications with connection to a Firebird database using FireDAC. It worked fine, but after Windows 10 update 1803, it cannot connect to database when I call application stored in network path (example: \comp1\share\myapp.exe or Q:\myapp.exe, Q: is mapped server path). Error status is 335544721 with illegal parameter.
The same build of application stored on local path works fine.

Comment: It might help to know what value the Database property is in each case. Debug to make absolutely certain it's the same.

Comment: what OS is running the share? The latest Win 10 forbids access to SMBv1 shares.

Comment: @whosrdaddy was that the reason they removed Home Group feature I wonder ?

Comment: What is connection string you pass to the database server?

Comment: Using databases on a shared drive by default is not possible, to do so would mean that a very unsafe feature would have been enabled in the Firebird config. You should always connect through a Firebird server on the machine hosting the database file. I do wonder though if the networking changes made in Windows 10.1803 maybe broke the Firebird WNET protocol.

Comment: A database is always stored on local disk! An application cannot connect to database when is copied to network path only. Connection string is: 'DriverID=FB;Password=masterkey;User_Name=SYSDBA;Database=c:\App\Express\Data\FKLIENT.FDB;Protocol=TCPIP;Server=SCORPIO-SSD;CharacterSet=WIN1250;Port=3050;PageSize=4096;SQLDialect=3;RoleName=RDB$ADMIN'

Comment: On share is Western Digital NAS Firmware, but before update Windows 10 it worked fine.

Comment: Can you connect from an isql console? If not please check  if the Firebird Service still exists on the server.

Comment: A recent post on the Firebird-support mailing list suggests that you may need to (re-enable) SMBv2 in the Windows configuration to fix the problem with Windows 10 v1803. This is a workaround though, you **should not** open Firebird databases on a network share. If you need to share a database with multiple computers, then one computer (preferably a server) should host the database and have Firebird server installed, and you should connect to the Firebird instance on that server using an alias or alternatively a local path, not a share.

Comment: You didn't understand my problem! I don't want open firebird stored in network shared! Only *.exe is on network store!

Comment: When I copy *.exe from network store to local store and run it from local store application works fine! Database is always on the same place!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem!! The reason is the Firebird version 1.5.x (maybe 2.5 too?). Windows Update 1803 blocks the communication between client and server. The only solution is to migrate to Firebird 3.0.x (or to uninstall the update - not a really good option).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Delphi application I developed a couple years ago. After an update to Windows 10 on one of my machines, it suddenly drops the connection to the Firebird server (2.5.0 in SuperServer mode) installed on a Windows 7 host, while my other hosts (Windows XP, Windows 2003, Windows 7 and 8.1) connect normally. When I ping or telnet to the server address from Windows 10 (telnet 192.168.1.X 3050), the connection establishes. I have tried everything like enabling SMBv1 and disabling v2 and v3, run it under a VM (Windows 7) machine inside Windows 10, I was surprised to not being able to connect either. Then I realised that it wasn't a network hardware configuration problem, but for unexplained reasons Windows Defender. I just disabled it, and then my app was able to connect.

Don't rely on Firebird's returned error messages, they don't describe the real issue, and can mislead you.

I forgot to mention that I did enable some services before disabling Windows Defender, which were disabled after windows update 1803:
Set both Function Discovery Services to Automatic and start them, SSDP Discovery set to automatic, UPnP Device Host set to automatic.